Make durable functions to return failure - when activity is failing
I'm facing an issue with my Azure Function App that's triggered by a pipeline. Initially, my function app would always return a success code, even if one of its activities failed. To fix this, I modified the code to check the status of the activity and return a failure code if it failed.
Here's the original code:
@myApp.route(route="orchestrators/xml_remit_gen", methods=["POST"])
@myApp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def http_xml_remit_gen(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient):
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        set_configurations(req_body, False)
        # Assuming no additional arguments are required for start_new
        instance_id = await client.start_new("xml_remit_gen_orchestrator", None, req_body)
        response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)
        return func.HttpResponse(error_message, status_code=500)

And here's the modified code:
@myApp.route(route="orchestrators/xml_remit_gen", methods=["POST"])
@myApp.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def http_xml_remit_gen(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient):
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        set_configurations(req_body, False)
        # Assuming no additional arguments are required for start_new
        instance_id = await client.start_new("xml_remit_gen_orchestrator", None, req_body)
         while True:
                 status = await client.get_status(instance_id)
                 if status.runtime_status in [df.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Failed, df.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Completed]:
                     break  
                 await asyncio.sleep(1)  

         if status.runtime_status in [df.OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Failed, 'Failed']:
             response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
             return client._create_http_response(500, status.output)
            
        response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)
        return func.HttpResponse(error_message, status_code=500)

However, after making this change, the pipeline is timing out automatically after 4 minutes. Initially i was facing this issue, which led me to consider using Azure Durable Functions, but I encountered same problem again. How can I resolve this timeout issue and ensure that the function app returns the appropriate success or failure code based on the activity's status?

How is your pipeline triggering your Function? Is it triggered by pipeline resource usage check to Invoke Azure Function with Completion event as callback? If yes, how have  you set the Timeout in the Control options of the check? Besides, I didn't see any callback request sent back to Azure DevOps authenticating against AuthToken specifying taskId, jobId or result. Please check Asynchronous checks and update your function to call into Azure DevOps.

Is your function triggered by Azure DevOps pipeline or Azure Data Factory pipeline?

We are using azure data factory web activity to trigger the function app, And the function is a http based trigger.

You are reaching out to the sub community of Azure DevOps since you are using the azure-pipelines tag. Please note azure-pipelines is the feature belonging to Azure DevOps rather than Azure Data Factory. You may consider updating the original post and reach out the correct team. Thx.

You haven't shared how the pipeline triggers your function. Let's assume your function is triggered by pipeline resource usage check to Invoke Azure Function with Completion event as callback, when the pipeline requests to use the resource, the check operation will trigger your function and wait for the callback request sent back to Azure DevOps from your function. If the check doesn't receive the callback request in a time limit configured in the Timeout settings in the Control options, the check will fail.
Furthermore, I didn't see any callback request sent back to Azure DevOps from your function, which should authenticate against AuthToken and specify taskId, jobId and result in the request body. Please check Asynchronous checks and update your function to call into Azure DevOps.


